# ListCollectionView grouping already grouped items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How can i make double grouping in ListCollectionView(by double grouping i mean not just grouping by two properties, but group what is already grouped by another property)?

example:

```
class Person{
     public string Name;
     public int Age;
{

List<Person> list = new List<Person>{
  new Person{ Name = Alex, Age = 22 },
  new Person{ Name = Alex, Age = 23 },
  new Person{ Name = Sam, Age = 19 },
  new Person{ Name = Sam, Age = 33 }
};
ListCollectionView listView = new ListCollectionView(list);
listView.GroupDescriptions.add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Name"));

that is all i have right now, is there some way?
```

**Alex:**

**22:**

Alex 22;

**23:**

Alex 23;

**Sam:**

**19:**

Sam 19;

**33:**

Sam 33;

Thank in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
var result= list.GroupBy(item => item.Name)
                .Select(group => new 
                { 
                    Name = group.Key,
                    Values = group.GroupBy(item => item.Age)
                                  .Select(innerGroup => new 
                                  { 
                                      Age = group.Key, 
                                      Values = group.ToList() 
                                  }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: can i use result in ListCollectionView after grouping? necause i need to bind it to the ListBox